# What should the return object of ServiceStack Authorize method be?

Tags: servicestack, saml-2.0

I am writing my own authorize provider for SAML2 authorization. To help me, I got a third party library to handle most of the SAML2 specification.

However this library is written for the ASP.NET `HttpHandler` interface where there is no return values for the `ProcessRequest` method.

With this library the method itself will not return anything, but takes care of most of my work of compressing the authentication request XML, creating the signature for the XML and telling the browser to redirect to SAML2 login page, with the correct attributes for the call. So it does a lot of work for me.

Some pseudo code:

```cs
public object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
{
    ...
    AuthnRequest authnRequestXML = saml2Util.CreateAuthnRequestXML();
    HttpResponseBase httpResponse = authService.Request.Response.OriginalResponse as HttpResponseBase;
    // This takes care of signing, compression of the authnRequestXML and the redirect action
    SAML2Library.SendAuthnRequestByHTTPRedirect(httpResponse, DestinationURL, authnRequestXML, certificatePrivateKey);
    return ?;
}
```

Return `null` didn't work. 
What should I set as the return value of the `Authenticate` method in this case?

Answer (score 2):

To return a redirect response you can return a `HttpResult` e.g:

```
return HttpResult.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

Comment: Didn't work. The redirect is already taken care of in the SendAuthnRequestByHTTPRedirect method. I lost the arguments needed for a proper SAML request.

Comment: One workaround for me seems to generate all the needed arguments for my redirect call and use the HttpResult.Redirect method.